# Find max value from different columns in a single row in scala DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to find out the max value from different columns in a single row in scala dataframe.

The data available in dataframe is as below.

```
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|    NUM|                                   SIG1|                                   SIG2|                                   SIG3|
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":1569560531000,"VALUE":3.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531001,"VALUE":4.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531002,"VALUE":2.7825}]|
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":1569560541001,"VALUE":1.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560541000,"VALUE":8.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560541003,"VALUE":5.7825}]|
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":1569560531000,"VALUE":3.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531009,"VALUE":3.7825}]|        null                           |
|XXXXX02|[{"TIME":1569560531000,"VALUE":5.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531007,"VALUE":8.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531006,"VALUE":3.7825}]|
|XXXXX02|[{"TIME":1569560531000,"VALUE":9.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531009,"VALUE":1.7825}]|[{"TIME":1569560531010,"VALUE":3.7825}]|
```

and the schema is

```
scala> DF.printSchema
root
 |-- NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SIG1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SIG2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SIG3: string (nullable = true)
```

The expected output is as below.

```
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+
|    NUM|      TIME    | SIG1|    |  SIG2      |  SIG3      |
+-------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+
|XXXXX01| 1569560531002| 3.7825   | 4.7825     | 2.7825     |
|XXXXX01| 1569560541003| 1.7825   | 8.7825     | 5.7825     |
|XXXXX01| 1569560531009| 3.7825   | 3.7825     | null       |
|XXXXX02| 1569560531007| 5.7825   | 8.7825     | 3.7825     |
|XXXXX02| 1569560531010| 9.7825   | 1.7825     | 3.7825     |
```

I need to add a new column with highest TIME from a single row and SIG columns with their value only.

Basically the TIME in each column will be replaced by the highest TIME value available in that row and explode the TIME and VALUEs.

Is there any UDF/functions to achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a column in Dataset which have array of key value pairs and find out a pair with max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128746/iterate-through-a-column-in-dataset-which-have-array-of-key-value-pairs-and-find)

Comment: I had already provided solution of same issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128746/iterate-through-a-column-in-dataset-which-have-array-of-key-value-pairs-and-find?noredirect=1#comment102648524_58128746

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_json_object` function to extract values from json stored as a string.

Then it's quite straightforward:

```
DF.withColumn("TIME", greatest(get_json_object('SIG1, "$[0].TIME"),
                               get_json_object('SIG2, "$[0].TIME"),
                               get_json_object('SIG3, "$[0].TIME")))
  .withColumn("SIG1", get_json_object('SIG1, "$[0].VALUE"))
  .withColumn("SIG2", get_json_object('SIG2, "$[0].VALUE"))
  .withColumn("SIG3", get_json_object('SIG3, "$[0].VALUE"))
  .show
```